# How to change the content of Google map infowindow?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How to show different content in infoWindow in Google map?
I have Google map and  a button .I have used infowindow to show the content. So my doubt is if I hover over the marker it should show "hello". but when I click on a button it should show me some value(Assuming that I have written function  to display some value)
Please note::hovering should display hello in infowindow and button should show some value

**JavaScript solution only**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var markers = [];
    function initialize() {

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.714364, -74.005972),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemap"), mapOptions);


            var locations = [
                ['New York', 40.714364, -74.005972, 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png']
            ];


            var marker, i;
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content:"Hello World!"
  });


            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.close();
            });


            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                    map: map,
                    icon: locations[i][3]
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));

                markers.push(marker);
            }
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });

        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        function myClick(id){
            google.maps.event.trigger(markers[id], 'click');
        }
</script>
<div id="googlemap" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="myClick(0);">Open Info Window</a>
```

**The Problem with the above solution is ::once you click on button  , content of info window changes permanently(It should change back to "hello" on hovering again)**

Answer (score 1):

If you want the content to change to "Hello" on 'mouseover', change it to "Hello" on 'mouseover'"

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
  infowindow.setContent("Hello");
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/bjyd2p8q/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var markers = [];

function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.714364, -74.005972),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemap"), mapOptions);


  var locations = [
    ['New York', 40.714364, -74.005972, 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png']
  ];


  var marker, i;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Hello World!"
  });


  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
  });


  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map,
      icon: locations[i][3]
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));

    markers.push(marker);
  }
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    infowindow.setContent("Hello");
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function myClick(id) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(markers[id], 'click');
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#googlemap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="myClick(0);">Open Info Window</a>
<div id="googlemap"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but i do have one more doubt how do i close the info window by clicking the button once again(assuming that infowindow is already open)

Comment: That would be a different question.  Please do some research and indicate what have you tried before asking it.